# API level error in android calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

When I write this code in android 4.1

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Field requires API level 14 (current min is 8): 
                   android.provider.CalendarContract$Events#CONTENT_URI
```

Please tell me how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   change android manifest.xml android:minSdkVersion="8" 8 to 14.
```

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file change

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

to

```
android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

Comment: thats nice but now i have problem of connecting the account with emulator